# highcharts displaying data on timechange

Tags: highcharts, dst

I'd like to plot data for several days (could be from from 1 to 7 days) using highcharts.

Data could be hourly or half hourly.

I'd like the display to be in local time (i.e. observes daylight saving).

I'd like the graph to be continuous, i.e. on spring time change, there's no 'gap' in the line, on winter timechange day, there's no doubling back (i.e. zig-zag) on timechange day.

a) Can highcharts handle this?

b) If not, could I instead plot in standard time (i.e. no time change) but label the x-axis with local time labels. if so:

b.1) can I specify labels to be displayed only when the local time label is 00:00 (rather than the standard time value) for when data is spanning several days and I only want a label on midnight when day changes in local time?

Many thanks for any help. I'm hoping there's already a jsfiddle example or something I've missed with my searching for a solution.

**[UPDATED WITH MY SOLUTION]**

I ended up solving this with specifying the xAxis categories and tickPositions to use.
This would plot summer time change days correctly (including the chart's xAxis ticks/grid lines)
I have an object (defined in C# and passed back via json to the javascript) which looks like this:

```
public class DataTableList
{
    public int numDays = 0;
    public List<string> heading = null;
    public List<List<string>> table = null;
};
```

and a function which would look at the number of days to plot and if it's one or two days, just plot the time, otherwise plot the date.
Also uses xAxisCategories to tell the chart where to plot the ticks (i.e. grid lines).

```
function RefreshChartData() {    
    if (_data == null)
        return;

    var datePos, timePos, load_fcstPos;

    //we will 'line up' chartTickPositions and xAxisCategories so there's a tick for each label
    var chartTickPositions = Array();   //values on the x axis to display labels (x axis just goes 0,1,2,3,...,n)
    var xAxisCategories = new Array();  //labels to display on the xAxis

    //find column positions for data we're interested in plotting
    for (var col = 0; col < _data.heading.length; col++)
    {
        if (_data.heading[col].toLowerCase() == 'date')
            datePos = col;
        if (_data.heading[col].toLowerCase() == 'time')
            timePos = col;
        if (_data.heading[col].toLowerCase() == 'load_fcst')
            load_fcstPos = col;
    }

    var seriesStr = [];  //y values to plot

    //iterate through table rows, extracting data to plot, sorting out chart tick labels, etc
    for (var row = 0; row < _data.table.length; row++) {
        //get number of days we're plotting
        var numDays = parseInt(_data.numDays);

        //extract values to plot from row
        var date = _data.table[row][datePos];
        var time = _data.table[row][timePos];
        var iTime = parseInt(time);
        var value = _data.table[row][load_fcstPos];

        //create xAxis Label
        switch (numDays) {
            case (1):
            case (2):
                if (iTime % 200 == 0) {
                    chartTickPositions.push(row);  //want to plot this label every two hours
                    xAxisCategories.push(time);
                }
                else
                    xAxisCategories.push('');
                break;
            case (3):
            case (4):
            case (5):
            case (6):
            case (7):
            default:
                //just return date
                if (iTime == 0) {
                    chartTickPositions.push(row);  //want to plot this label midnight every day
                    xAxisCategories.push(date);
                }
                else
                    xAxisCategories.push('');
        }

        //add value to series to plot
        seriesStr.push(parseInt(value, 10));
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({   //buid up our chart javascript to be triggered on client browser

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chartContainer',
            animation: false,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        //http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis
        xAxis: {
            categories: xAxisCategories,
            tickPositions: chartTickPositions,
            gridLineWidth: '1',
            lineWidth: 1,
            labels: {
                rotation: -90,
                align: 'right'
                //},
                //formatter: function () {
                //    return chartFormatter(this.value);
                //}                
            }
        },

        //http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series
        series: [{
            data: seriesStr,
            draggableY: false,
            color: 'green'
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify whether you want to display your graph in local time on the server, or local time on the client.

Conceptually what you want to do is store your data in UTC time and then apply a local time zone offset to it, either on the server before passing it to Highcharts or on the client side.

On the client side you'd use something like:

```
var myStartDateTimeInUTC = <assumed to be initialized in milliseconds>;
var d = new Date();
var timeZoneOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 3600;
```

getTimezoneOffset() returns offset in minutes so you need to multiply by 3600 to convert to milliseconds.

```
series: [{
   data: [ your data here ],
   pointStart: myStartDateTimeInUTC - timeZoneOffset
}]
```

How you'd do this server side depends on what technology you are using, but the principle would be the same.

This will result in a continuous graph at all times.

Comment: Thanks for a speedy reply! I ended up thinking about this and coming up with a different solution. I have edited my original answer.
I'm not wanting to convert the dates/times to whatever timezone the client is in, just wanting to display data in local time and have it handle time change days. e.g. French data would be in French local time, regardless of where the client is.